# google map not loading 2nd time in java script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sapui5

In SAP UI5, google map is not loading for the second time. I am loading the map on attachPatternMatched() function. So, how can I resolve this issue?

```
 onInit: function() {
        var that = this;

        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.getRoute("master").attachPatternMatched(this.setMapData, this);
```

},

```
setMapData: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.getView().getModel("BookMyRideModel").read("/Stops", {
            success: function(response) {
                var arry = [];
                for (var k = 0; k < response.results.length; k++) {
                    var lat = response.results[k].Latitude;
                    var long = response.results[k].Longitude;
                    var address = response.results[k].Stop_Name;
                    var pincode = response.results[k].Pincode;
                    var id = response.results[k].Stop_Id;
                    arry.push({
                        "lat": lat,
                        "long": long,
                        "addr": address,
                        "pin": pincode,
                        "key": id
                    });
                }
                that.setMarkerForMap(arry);
            },
            error: function(response) {

            }
        });

    },
  setMarkerForMap: function(array) {
        var that = this;
        var markersarry = [];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(12.9715), 
                    parseFloat(77.5945626)),
                    zoom: 2,
             mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
  }
```

**There in setMapForMarkers() I'm loading multiple markers on Map which are coming from oData service.**

```
        [After clicking other tabs in master page, and later on clicking Bokk my ride tab , that time facing the issue][1]
```

Thanks & Regards,
Raheen

[snap of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxN9j.png)

Answer (score 0):

The onInit function is executed when your component is initialized. This method is only called once so that explains why your map is not loaded the second time. You might want to try and add your function in the onAfterRendering() function.

Comment: there also i have added and tried. But still map is not getting loaded on split app (detail part).